# Get File inside Array of Files Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dynamic inputs of file in html so i add each file in array of file

```
   tmp_files :File[] = [] ;
```

and in HTML

```
 <div class="container">
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile">
```

in component filechange function look like this

```
fileChange(event) {
this.tmp_files.push(event.target.files);}
```

and save function

```
save(){
 for (let i = 0; i < this.tmp_files.length; i++) {
        console.log("ccc",this.tmp_files[i]);

      }
}
```

So in console log i get files [image]

So now i tried to get File and File name, i spent a lot of time , i tried a lot of thing, but i can't resolve this issue so thanks to help me to Get File and her name because i want to send this files to server thanks again

Comment: Can you `console.log("ccc", JSON.stringify(this.tmp_files))` before the loop instead? It's difficult to tell what exactly is going on from a screenshot of an object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `File` type is an object with the first numerical index being the `File` itself. Not sure how this happened, but it might be a good idea to flatten out (Or maybe that's just Typescript's browser typing, I don't know).

You would get hold of it like so:

```
save() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.tmp_files.length; i++) {
        console.log('File:', this.tmp_files[i][0], 'Name:', this.tmp_files[i][0].name);
      }
}
```

or more cleanly in ES6 standards:

```
save(filename: string) {
    const myFile = this.tmp_files.find(s => s[0].name === filename);
    // do stuff with MyFile
}
```